# Magento Upgrade to 1.9.2.2 Gives Wrong CSS & JS Path

Tags: php, magento

After upgrading my magento site from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.2.2 some css file path within head tag was set wrong. I found out that getCssJsHtml() function was returning absolute path to the css files(/home/username/public_html/skin/..../style.css) instead of correct url(http://siteurl/skin/..../style.css). So I manually changed the getCssJsHtml() function in app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Head.php
Now the css path is ok but I want to know, what's the reason for this issue and is there any smarter way to fix this?

Comment: Are you using an Addon like GT Speed do combine/reduce your JS and CSS files? uninstall it and the problem will solved.

Comment: No, there is no addon like that to compress JS/CSS files

Answer (score 1):

well

System => Configuration => Web

The main point to watch out for is

i. Url options -> Add store code to Urls should be 'No'

ii. Unsecure -> Base Url should point to your own domain e.g http://mycommerce.com/

iii. Secure -> Base Url should point to your own domain e.g http://mycommerce.com/

also you should have

{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/

for your Base Skin

Comment: The settings are exactly as described here. I guess these settings are saved in the database and it was not changed during the update

Comment: A much simpler approach is to just head over to magento database and alter the table core_config_data manually. There should be an entry named dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_files.
These two should hold values of 1.By setting these two values to 0, you'll get this fixed and your css and js files should be loadable again

Comment: Yes I cleared the cache. I only found dev/js/merge_files in core_config_data with value 0. I think the JS/CSS path is being loaded from a file, not from database

Comment: did you checked the permission of skin and media folder? follow http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html for file permission if not set